# How to align a child div to the top of its parent div which is scrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll

Using css,
I want the the div(.scroll-indicator) to always cover parent div(.scroll-container), but when you scroll you see that it scrolls along with its content.

https://jsfiddle.net/vish6263/srnjyvtm/16/

Basically position: sticky is a hybrid of relative and fixed
Is there a solution for a hybrid of absolute and fixed?

Update: I already have it working by wrapping it without another container but since this is a re-usable component I am developing I didn want to add another layer inbetween, so was wondering if there is a solution using CSS only?

```css
.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.scroll-item {
  height: 50px;
}

.scroll-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='scroll-container'>
  <div class='scroll-indicator'>
  
  </div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item1</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item2</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item3</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item4</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item5</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set `.scroll-indicator {position: sticky; ...` ?

Comment: Set `.scroll-indicator {position: relative; ...` ?

Comment: are the width/height always known?

Comment: @Kosh sticky wont work, as mentioned since it is a combination of relative and fixed, it will occupy space within the container

Comment: @TemaniAfif
Well there will be a height I am sure since it will have scrolling content inside but width may be not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the height you can try the following:

```css
.scroll-container {
  --h: 200px; /* the height */
  
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: var(--h);
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.scroll-item {
  height: 50px;
}

.scroll-indicator {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: inherit;
  margin-bottom: calc(-1*var(--h));
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<div class='scroll-container'>
  <div class='scroll-indicator'>

  </div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item1</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item2</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item3</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item4</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item5</div>
  <div class='scroll-item'>item6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is really nice stuff, thanks a lot. Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the items in another div;

```css
.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
}

.scroll-item {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.scroll-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.scroll-items {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='scroll-container'>
  <div class='scroll-indicator'>

  </div>
  <div class="scroll-items">
    <div class='scroll-item'>item1</div>
    <div class='scroll-item'>item2</div>
    <div class='scroll-item'>item3</div>
    <div class='scroll-item'>item4</div>
    <div class='scroll-item'>item5</div>
    <div class='scroll-item'>item6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: fixed issue because I forgot to update it from my JsFiddle

Comment: I am currently using it by wrapping it with another container, but when creating a re-usable component it wasnt ideal so wanted to know without wrapping

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? An inside border around the content?

Comment: no an arrow mark pointing down and/or up depending on where the scroll content is